# Is there a way to extract numbers from an Excel value given certain conditions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have four values:

```
OT 10    
OT 11 1AT    
1P; OT 12
OT 13; 10P
```

Using this formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("OT",C1)),IF(SUM(LEN(C1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C1, {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"}, "")))>0, SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&C1, LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(C1,ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$"&LEN(C1))),1))* ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$"&LEN(C1))),0), ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$"&LEN(C1))))+1,1) * 10^ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$"&LEN(C1)))/10),""),)
```

I'm able to convert those values to these values:

```
10    
111    
112
1310
```

Is there a way to fix this formula so that it only pulls the number adjacent to "OT", directly to the right, with exactly one space in between? The correct output would be:

```
10    
11    
12
13
```

The output can be a two or three-digit number only, if the original value is `OT 100 2AT`, then output should be `100`.

Comment: Is it always a two digit number?

Comment: It's always a 2-3 digit number (ie: OT 10 or OT 210)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the number after the `OT`:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A4,FIND("OT",A4)+3,FIND(" ",REPLACE(A4&" ",1,FIND("OT",A4)+3,""))),";",""),"/","")
```

NEST other

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, the formula mostly works except it breaks if there is a symbol next to the OT number. For example, if the input is OT 20; then the formula doesn't work.

Comment: @itsharman you did not show that to be an option.  Please show all possible entries.

Comment: Sorry about that, that's the final exception. The number after OT may have a ; or /

Answer (score 0):

=SUBSTITUTE(MID(C1,FIND("OT",C1)+3,3)," ","")

Or in case there should be only ; or / somewhere:
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(C1,FIND("OT",C1)+3,3)," ",""),";",""),"/","")

```js
var src = 'OT 10    |OT 11 1AT    |1P; OT 12|OT 13; 10P|OT 14/ 10P'.split('|');
for(var i=0;i<src.length;i++) {
   var pos = src[i].indexOf('OT');
   console.log("FIND OT (XL) position", pos+1, "MID", src[i].substr(pos+3,3).replace(/;/g,'').replace(/\//g,''));
}
```

Comment: See the comments made on my answer. The OP could have `OT 20;` Your formula will return `20;` and not `20`